# MarkLogic Optic API: Filtering rows with op:where() with timestamps older than 30 days

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

In my dataset I have a field testDateTime that contains xs:dateTime timestamps: `2022-06-02T10:42:00Z`

Using the optic API and `op:where()`, is there a way I can filter my results to exclude any rows with timestamps older than 30 days?

I have been attempting to use the following SQL statements in `op:like-sql-condition()` but do not look to be supported:

```
=>op:where(op:sql-condition("MyData.testDateTime < CURRENT_DATE - 30"))
=>op:where(op:sql-condition("MyData.testDateTime < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())"))
=>op:where(op:sql-condition("MyData.testDateTime < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY"))
=>op:where(op:sql-condition("MyData.testDateTime < GETDATE() - 30"))
```

Is there a way to get this working either with a SQL condition or with optic operators themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just using [`op:lt()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/op:lt) and testing whether the `testDateTime` column is less than `currentDateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration("P30D")`:

```
=> op:where(op:lt(op:col("MyData.testDateTime"), current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration("P30D")))
```